# AttributeError: "Dialog" object has no attribute 'setupUi'

Tags: python, class, qt-designer, qdialog

I made two forms on pyqt5 - qt-designer. One is the Main Form and the second is a Dialog which I will use for user input. I converted both to py code.

First of all I should inform you that I do not modify the converted Ui.py files. I prefer to have an extra "Main" file where I set each modification. I do this so that I won't have to make the extra changes each time I modify with the Ui files.

So, I added a second class on my Main file and tried to call it from my MainForm Class through a menu item. Here is some example code:

```
class MainForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainForm()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.actionMenu1.triggered.connect(self.open_my_dialog)

    def open_my_dialog(self):
        my_dialog = QDialog()
        my_dialog.ui = MyDialog()
        my_dialog.ui.setupUi(my_dialog)
        # MainForm.hide(self)
        my_dialog.exec_()
        my_dialog.show()


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MyDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_cancel.clicked.connect(self.cancel_dialog)

    def cancel_dialog(self):
        print("Closing Dialog Window...")
        sys.exit()
```

When I run this and click the respective menu button I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MyDialog' object has no attribute 'setupUi'
```

the Error is at this line:

```
self.ui.setupUi(self)  # this is under MyDialog Class
```

I can get the code working if I reference it to the external (Ui_MyDialog) file directly without using the second class here. But as I stated at the beginning I want to control this from within this file, make the modifications directly here so that I won't have the keep track of the modifications to the Ui files in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it to work. But before I provide the answer, I would like to thank 
@p-a-o-l-o and @LoïcG.. the latter helping me out all the way. Thanks!

The code worked when I changed it to the following:

```
class MainForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainForm()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.actionMenu1.triggered.connect(self.open_my_dialog)

    def open_my_dialog(self):
        my_dialog = MyDialog()
        # my_dialog.show()  <-- seems this line is not necessary either
        my_dialog.exec_()  # this alone was enough for the code to work


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MyDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton_cancel.clicked.connect(self.cancel_dialog)

    def cancel_dialog(self):
        print("Closing Dialog Window...")
        self.close()  # not important but corrected this also.
```

I hope this helps!

Edit: I corrected some lines and made the answer more simple thanks to
@LoïcG. !

Comment: I don't think this code works. You call `my_dialog.show()` while `my_dialog` is undefined.

Comment: @LoïcG. my apologies.. correcting it now.. Corrected those two lines by: MyDialog().show() and MyDialog().exec_()

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't work. No need to test it. Also you do not need to call `MyDialog().ui.setupUi(QDialog())` since `self.ui.setupUi(self)` is already called into the constructor of  `MyDialog`

Comment: I corrected it. The code worked but I was using the code on the post and copy pasting it.. forgot to edit the 2 lines there. Sorry again. The code does work the way it is. Please undo your downvote if you see fit @LoïcG.

Comment: Sorry but `MyDialog().exec_()` should be enough to open your dialog. Currently, you instantiate 3 times `MyDialog`

Comment: @LoïcG. Yes, I tried removing that line and it did work too. I didn't know it was that easy. Thank you.. I will try to comment that part out now.

Comment: @LoïcG. The code doesnt work if i comment out exec_() , but does work when (only) show() is commented out. Is that the proper way to do it? Should I not use show and just exec_?

Comment: I never say to comment out `exec_()` but I said `MyDialog().exec_()` should be enough. Please read [the doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html) to learn what these methods do. Furthermore, as already said too, you currently instanciate two times `MyDialog` : first time with `MyDialog().show()` and second time with `MyDialog().exec_()`. To avoid that, you have to pass a reference to the instance : `d = MyDialog()`

Comment: @LoïcG. Can you check my answer again? Is this the proper way to do it? I tried to change it according to your feedback.

Comment: It's better but calling `my_dialog.show()` before `my_dialog.exec_()` is useless.

Comment: @LoïcG. I apologies for taking so much of your time. Just to be clear, should I not use show() when calling my dialog? If so I will just delete that line in my answer. Or when you said "before" did you mean that I should write the show() line AFTER the exec_? Thank you for your patience. I'm new as you can understand and want to learn the proper way of coding.

Comment: According to [the doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html#exec), `QDialog.exec_()` shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it. You do not need to call `QWidget.show()` for showing you dialog.

Comment: @LoïcG. Thanks again. Updated the answer now. It seems so easy but took time for me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the error occurs at this line

```
self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

and you assigned an `Ui_MyDialog` instance to `self.ui`, before

```
self.ui = Ui_MyDialog()
```

the error message should be mentioning class `Ui_MyDialog` and not `MyDialog`.

So, either you misreported the error message or the error does not occur 'under MyDialog Class'.

I also would point out: `QWidget` and derived classes have no `setupUi` method, themselves. Such method belongs to `Ui_*` classes, generated by *uic*, and is typically called from the constructor of a widget that **inherits from** a `Ui_*` class.

So, if you want to call `setupUi` on `MyDialog` instances, `MyDialog` must inherit from `Ui_MyDialog`, in the first place.

And you **do** call it in `open_my_dialog`:

```
my_dialog.ui = MyDialog()
my_dialog.ui.setupUi(my_dialog)
```

Comment: The external file Ui_MyDialog has:

    `class Ui_MyDialog(object):`
        `def setupUi(self, MyDialog):`
            `# the code from converting the qt-deigner file`

Shouldn't it refernce to that from my Class in the main file? I use this way for the MainForm and it works without an issue, it too calls the setupUi in the same manner.

Comment: Thank you @p-a-o-l-o
I entered the answer after testing everything that I could think of. I wanted to upvote your answer but since I'm new it did not let me do so. I hope the answer I provided is the correct way to go. :)